# I don't know how to get piece of python coded

Tags: python

*the text in the code is in Dutch, sorry about that*,

I'm working on python for school and I'm making a vending machine but when I want to make the pay system I get get further, what I have is 3 dictionaries, one with the number and product, one with the same number and the price and one other which uses the first dictionary keys and the second values to create a third one.

I now have is that the first one is shown and you pick a number. then it goes to to the payment section, and there is the problem, you get asked with how much you want to pay, then it needs to make a sum, your input - price, and the price I don't know how to get, i need to get the value of the 2 or 3 dictionary but the code needs to know what value while you pick from other dictionary,  can anyone help me?

```
CODE:
import pprint

def kiezen():
  pprint.pprint(keuzes_automaat)
  keuze = int(input(f"Hallo, maak je keuze tussen 5 en 15 voor wat je wilt. \n" 'welke keuze heeft u gemaakt?   '))
  if keuze >= 5 and keuze <=15 in keuzes_automaat:
    print('hallo')
  else:
    print("sorry deze keuze is niet mogelijk, maak alstublieft een andere keuze \n herstart de script opnieuw en kies alstublieft een keuze tussen 5 en 15")
    kiezen()

def betalen():
  geld = int(input(f"met hoeveel wilt u betalen?    "))
  for k in keuzes_automaat.keys():
    for v in keuzes_automaat_betaal.values():
      rekenen[k] = v
  bedrag = geld - rekenen(keuzes_automaat).values()
  print(f"het geld dat u terug krijgt is:")


keuzes_automaat_betaal = {
  5: 0.90,
  6: 0.90,
  7: 0.90,
  8: 0.90,
  9: 0.90,
  10: 0.90,
  11: 0.90,
  12: 0.90,
  13: 0.90,
  14: 0.90,
  15: 0.90,
}

keuzes_automaat = {
  5: "roze koek, 0,90$",
  6: "gevulde koek",
  7: "stroopwafels",
  8: "maoam pinballs",
  9: "lays bolognese",
  10: "dorrito cool american flavour",
  11: "dorrito nacho cheese",
  12: "dorrito sweet chili peper",
  13: "dorrito roulette",
  14: "dorrito flamin hot nacho cheese",
  15: "lays paprika",
}
rekenen = {}

kiezen()

betalen()

print(rekenen)

----------
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Your explanation is extremely confusing. Could you provide some example input and output?

Comment: Is the user/customer only selecting 1 item from the vending machine or multiple items?

Comment: the customer is selecting 1 item and, see it like this: you get a dictionary shown ther ypu pick what u want thenit uses the other dictionary with the prizes to wwork, but how do you set the innput equal to the key of a dictionary?